# Unscramble RGB raster - 4D interpolation/lookup

Tags: qgis, r

I have a 4-band raster image (RGB), downloaded from a WMS, representing clay content of topsoil ranging from brown (high clay content) to yellow (low clay content). The 4th band is alpha-band, with constant 255 values.

[image: Part of image]

Instead of the red, green, blue values (all of them ranging from 0 to 255) the concentration is needed (ranging from 0 to 100). As a help, at certain points, I have the corresponding percentage (see the image above). That means, I have a lookup table like this:

R,    G,    B ,   percentage

244,  229,  115,  9

242,  187,   62,  26

220,  148,   37,  33

183,   97,    6,  41

177,   87,    1,  43

...

The question is, how can I get the value of clay content in percentage for every raster pixel.

For me this looks much like an interpolation task; however, resample, interp, approx work only in fewer dimensions.

[Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119572/extract-all-unique-values-from-a-rgb-raster) is a similar problem however with a different color ramp.

Comment: Any chance of a link to the image or the WMS from where it came? Or a similar image? Or even just a peek at part of the image?

Comment: And how is this a four-band raster image? R,G,B and something else? Is there an alpha or opacity channel?

Comment: Outline: A colour palette should be a continuous path in 3d R-G-B space. Get the unique colours in your image and plot them using `rgl::plot3d` and you should see them form a path - although it might not be straight or even smooth. You then need to construct the path using (probably) nearest neighbours and then you can interpolate...

Comment: Just for clarity, does the actual image have the spots with the value labels on, or is it a very clean raster with no annotations?

Comment: A fairly simplistic approach would be to create a multiple linear regression between the extracted percentage and the R-G-B values. That should give you a formula to go from the 3 values to the 1 value. It is likely not going to be perfect, but it is a place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a monochromatic palette (shades of yellow/brown) so there's a good chance some linear combination of the individual RGB values to a single value will work.

Your point sample data looks like this:

```
> train
    R   G   B percentage
1 244 229 115          9
2 242 187  62         26
3 220 148  37         33
4 183  97   6         41
5 177  87   1         43
```

Plotting some scatter plots of each component against percentage shows the Blue component to be near-linear:

```
> plot(train$B, train$percentage)
```

[image]

So we can predict percentage from Blue by fitting a linear model:

```
> m = lm(percentage~B, data=train)
```

Now we create a template raster and fill it with predicted percentages over the blue pixel values and plot:

```
> percent = p[[1]]
> percent[] = predict(m, newdata=data.frame(B=p[[3]][]))
> plot(percent)
```

[image]

this is a single band raster with percentage values. The holes are where I had to crop out the point labels from your image with NA values - if you have a clean source image then this shouldn't be a problem.

If this is good enough then stop, otherwise if you want better you could go into more complicated modelling based on all RGB components, or fitting a line through the path in RGB space, or asking the people who produced the data for a key, all depending on the level of precision you need in your application, which we don't know.